# Eclipse CDT code formatter with scientfic numbers (e notation)

Tags: eclipse, numbers, eclipse-cdt, formatter

Is there a way to keep the Eclipse code formatter from modifying a statement with a scientific number like this

```
  return 1.0e-2;
```

into

```
  return 1.0
e-2;
```

?

Update: It seems as if some code before these lines causes the problems. I'll try to figure out more, but it may take while. 
However, the built-in formatter settings work.

Version used: Mars 4.5.1 / CDT 8.8 with custom format settings.

Update: Ok, after some trial and error I found several scenarios where this occurs but it is hard to figure out what exactly the problem is. Several things (in the code before the numbers) that seem to have an impact are:

- template class member function
- if without brackets (followed by if with a code block)
- very long statements
- line ends with ;;

Update: I think the if part:

```
if (something)
  if (andthis)
  { 
     for (...) 
     {...} 
   }
```

was the main cause of the problems. I added some brackets and the error disappeared.
If some of those things mentioned before were not present, then the missing brackets would not cause any problems.

Comment: I have tried with Mars.1 and CDT 8.8 and I cannot reproduce this behaviour with any of the built-in formatters. Which version of CDT are you using and which formatter settings are you using?

Comment: Using also Mars 4.5.1 / CDT 8.8 and custom formatter settings. However, I extracted the piece of code causing this problem into another file and the error did not occur. Maybe some code before this lines messes up with the formatter. (Built in format settings work.)

Comment: Sounds like a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT). [Contributions welcome!](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) You have already done a great job narrowing it down. If you file a bug report with a minimal test case and attach your formatter setting it will increase the chance of someone else fixing it if you are not able to work on a solution.

Comment: Just submitted a bug report.

Comment: The bug is [487625](http://eclip.se/487625) if anyone wants to follow the discussion there.